# Saving arrays and strings to binary file in Python

Tags: python, arrays, string, python-2.7, binary

I have a series of arrays, each with a name associated
eg name 1
   array 1
   name 2
   array 2

I will have thousands of these, and would like to save them as a binary file.

Can anyone help with how to save these?

Thanks

Comment: are these `numpy` arrays?

Comment: Try [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) module.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what do you exactly mean by *array* (list, numpy array, ...). A good start is to look at the [pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) module.